# Erratic Problems Adding User ID to MySQL Table of User Lists

Tags: mysql

I have a site where users can log-in and add items to a list.

The user logs in and the session stores their e-mail, which I use to identify them in a user table.

Then, they can input a list item and add to a list table that contains their ID and their list items.

Sometimes the ID is added and sometimes it comes up null (however, the list item text is always added).  This seems erratic because most of the time the ID is included.

Any ideas?  The table type is MyISAM.  I'm new to programming, btw.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$item = $_REQUEST['item'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

if ($item)
{

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("We couldn't connect!");

mysql_select_db("table");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM users WHERE email='".$_SESSION['email']."'");
$result = mysql_result($query,0);
$user_id = $result;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (user_ID,item_name) VALUES('$user_id','$item')");
```

So every time I test it by logging into my site myself, no problems.  But increasingly, I have users who try to add items and it creates a record where item_name shows up correctly but user_ID is set to 0 (default).

Comment: Perhaps their session has timed out? Session start would create a new one minus the email.

Comment: Why not store the user_id in the session? That way, you wouldn't have to query for it every time you want to insert an item. Also, your code is wide-open to SQL injection attack. You really should do `$item = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item']);` because someone could inject SQL code into the request and you'd damn well want to protect against it. Better yet learn how to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its support for [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to interact with your database. The mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, read what I said about SQL injection attacks in the comments to your question.

It would be a good idea to store the `user_id` in the `$_SESSION` so you wouldn't have to query for it every time based on the email... but if you insist on just having the email in the `$_SESSION`, then you actually only need one query. Adjusted code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$item = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['item']);

if (!empty($item) && isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("We couldn't connect!");
    mysql_select_db("table");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (user_ID, item_name) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM users WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'), '$item')");
}
```

Like Jeff Watkins said, the session could be timed out, so it would be a good idea to first check if it's set using `isset()`.

Otherwise if you stored the userid in the session, you could just reference it directly as `$_SESSION['user_id']` instead of doing a subquery in the insert.